# How do I avoid the implicit "^" and "$" in Java regular expression matching?

Tags: java, regex

I've been struggling with doing some relatively straightforward regular expression matching in Java 1.4.2.  I'm much more comfortable with the Perl way of doing things.  Here's what's going on:

I am attempting to match /^<foo>/ from "<foo><bar>"

I try:

```
Pattern myPattern= Pattern.compile("^<foo>");
Matcher myMatcher= myPattern.matcher("<foo><bar>");
System.out.println(myMatcher.matches());
```

And I get "false"

I am used to saying:

```
print "<foo><bar>" =~ /^<foo>/;
```

which does indeed return true.

After much searching and experimentation, I discovered  [this](http://book.javanb.com/java-regular-expressions-taming-the-java-util-regex-engine/LiB0055.html) which said:

"The String method further optimizes its search criteria by placing an invisible ^ before the pattern and a $ after it."

When I tried:

```
Pattern myPattern= Pattern.compile("^<foo>.*");
Matcher myMatcher= myPattern.matcher("<foo><bar>");
System.out.println(myMatcher.matches());
```

then it returns the expected true.  I do not want that pattern though.  The terminating .* should not be necessary.

Then I discovered the Matcher.useAnchoringBounds(boolean) method.  I thought that expressly telling it to not use the anchoring bounds would work.  It did not.  I tried issuing a

```
myMatcher.reset();
```

in case I needed to flush it after turning the attribute off.  No luck.  Subsequently calling .matches() still returns false.

What have I overlooked?

Edit:
Well, that was easy,  thanks.

Comment: FYI, useAnchoringBounds() and useTransparentBounds() only come into play when you've used the region() method to limit matches to a subset of the original target text. If you haven't done that, those methods have no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the Matcher [find](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method (instead of the [matches](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) method)

Answer (score 3):

[`Matcher.useAnchoringBounds()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#useAnchoringBounds(boolean)) was added in JDK1.5 so if you are using 1.4, I'm not sure that it would help you even if it did work (notice the `@since 1.5` in the Javadocs).

The Javadocs for `Matcher` also state that [the `match()` method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()):

> Attempts to match the **entire** region against the pattern.

(emphasis mine)

Which explains why you only got `.matches() == true` when you changed the pattern to end with `.*`.

To match against the region starting at the beginning, but not necessarily requiring that the entire region be matched, use either the [`find()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) or [`lookingAt()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt()) methods.

Comment: btw, I don't think the part about "adding an invisible ^ and $" is correct - it's just that the matches() method behaves in a way as if you did - it only returns true if you match the _entire_ string.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the "match", what part of the input string do you expect to find?

In other words,

```
Matcher myMatcher= myPattern.matcher("<foo><bar>");
if (myMatcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println(myMatcher.group(0));
}
```

… should print what?

If you are expecting it to print just "`<foo>`", use the `find()` method on `Matcher` instead of `matches()`. If you really want to find matches when the input *starts* with "`<foo>`", then you need to explicitly indicate that with a `'^'`.

If you are expecting it to match "`<foo><bar>`", you need to include the trailing "`.*`".